# How to get 1/4 2/4 3/4 and 4/4 of a minutes in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Its bit difficult to explain, but I will try. 
I am having a couple of values like in HH:MM
    48:12 
    56:52
    11:59

I need to get the closed quarter value in percentage.

```
48.12 Should be 48.25
56.52 Should be 52.75
11:59 Should be 12:00
```

Is it possible in sql server

Below is my query. TotalTime is varchar

```
SELECT  (datediff(second, 0,  TotalTime) / (60.0 * 60.0))
```

**I cannot use CTE. I cannot create a function. It needs to be done select query.**

Comment: What's the data type?

Comment: Data type is varchar. I have updated my question

Comment: The datatype of `TotalTime` is `VARCHAR`?

Comment: This `56.52 Should be 52.75` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I guess when you run your query you get an error - always post the error. Since your datatype is varchar I also suggest you check how clean your data is with this query: `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE TotalTime NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'`

Comment: DO you reckon it should be 53

Comment: no the query runs fine

Comment: Shouldn't `48:12` be `48:15`, `56:52` be `57:00`, and `11:59` be `12:00`?

Comment: It would be good if I can get those result too. As I am looking for the second closed to its percentage type. like 48:12 so 12 seconds is like close to 25 % of total seconds.

Comment: Can you create an sql fiddle? Or generate a create and insert script?

Comment: You are looking for fractions of secondes. Once you write `48:12` at another place you put a dot `48.12`... Am I right if I assume, that the 48 is the second and the 12 is the fraction? Is it in hundreds? Is there `48.87` possible?

Comment: Shouldn't you change the title to *fractions of a minute* then?

Comment: Sorry My mistake. Its HH:MM

Answer (score 2):

Could be done this way. The function is taken from other posts here regarding time rounding

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] (@Time datetime, @RoundTo float)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RoundedTime smalldatetime
   DECLARE @Multiplier float

   SET @Multiplier= 24.0/@RoundTo

   SET @RoundedTime= ROUND(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(varchar,@Time,121) AS datetime) AS float) * @Multiplier,0)/@Multiplier

   RETURN @RoundedTime
END

DECLARE @A VARCHAR(5)

SELECT @A = CONVERT(CHAR(5),CAST(dbo.roundtime('13:14',0.25) AS TIME),108)


select LEFT(@A,2) + '.' + CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@A,4,2) AS FLOAT) / 60 * 100 AS CHAR(2))
```

Comment: I cannot create a function. It needs to be done select query.

Comment: @maxspan This is getting ridiculous... You can use a function *within* as select query...

Comment: I know you can use function but I am not allowed to create function.

Comment: @maxspan no CTE? no functions - put in your question, please!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this, no CTE, no function,just `SELECT`

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(funnytime VARCHAR(5));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('48:12'),('56:52'),('11:59');

SELECT CAST('00:' + REPLACE(STR(FinalTbl.TheMinute,2),' ','0') + ':' + REPLACE(STR(FinalTbl.TheSecond,2),' ','0') AS TIME) TheRoundedTime
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN TheSecond BETWEEN 52 AND 60 THEN TheMinute+1 ELSE TheMinute END AS TheMinute
          ,CASE WHEN TheSecond BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN 0 
                WHEN TheSecond BETWEEN 7 AND 21 THEN 15
                WHEN TheSecond BETWEEN 22 AND 36 THEN 30
                WHEN TheSecond BETWEEN 37 AND 51 THEN 45
                ELSE 0 END TheSecond
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Splitted.ToXML.value('/x[1]','int') TheMinute
              ,Splitted.ToXML.value('/x[2]','int') TheSecond
        FROM
        (
            SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(funnytime ,':','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) ToXML
            FROM @tbl
        ) AS Splitted
    ) AS TimeVals
) AS FinalTbl
```

Comment: In your question it sounds like you need this as `.25 / .30 / .45`. In this case just let the `CASE` return these values and omit the final `CAST`to `TIME`...

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TimeString VARCHAR(MAX) = '17:34'
DECLARE @Time Time = CAST(@TimeString AS TIME)
SELECT DATEPART(hour,@Time) + (DATEPART(minute,@Time)/15) * 0.25 + ROUND(CAST(DATEPART(minute,@Time) % 15 AS FLOAT)/15, 0) * 0.25
```

Comment: Hi Dennis Its pretty close. I need only HH:MM.

Comment: Can you remove seconds. I don't need seconds just Hour and min

Comment: Is it possible to remove the seconds from time I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace cte with Your Table Name. Something like this I suppose:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
('48:12'),
('45:30'),
('56:52'),
('11:59'),
('11:00')
) as t(v)
)

SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(RIGHT(c.v,2) as int) between 46 and 59  THEN CAST((CAST(LEFT(c.v,2) as int) + 1) as nvarchar(2)) + ':' 
            WHEN CAST(RIGHT(c.v,2) as int) = 0 THEN LEFT(c.v,2) + ':' 
            ELSE LEFT(c.v,2) + '.' END
          +
        CASE WHEN CAST(RIGHT(c.v,2) as int) between 1 and 15 THEN '25'
        WHEN CAST(RIGHT(c.v,2) as int) between 16 and 30 THEN '50'
        WHEN CAST(RIGHT(c.v,2) as int) between 31 and 45 THEN '75'
        WHEN CAST(RIGHT(c.v,2) as int) between 46 and 59 THEN '00' 
        WHEN CAST(RIGHT(c.v,2) as int) = 0 THEN '00' END as ColumnName
FROM cte c
```

Output:

```
ColumnName
48.25
45.50
57:00
12:00
11:00
```

Comment: I cannot use CTE. It needs to be done in select query

Comment: @maxspan What is your problem with *CTE and select query*?

Comment: Can we be sure, that both portions are always of two digits? Are there ever leading zeros?

Comment: @Shnugo thanks, I felt something is wrong with that query :)

Comment: @maxspan `cte` is for example of your table, `digits` can be represent as `CASE WHEN` part of a query.

Comment: both portion are always 2 digits

Comment: @maxspan please, check

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer.

```
DECLARE @TotalTime varchar(max)
SET @TotalTime = '48:12'
    Select ROUND(( DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0, CAST(@TotalTime as Time))/60.00)/25, 2) * 25 AS [Rounded Hours]
```

This will give me 48:25 as answer.

Comment: I am affraid, that casting "48:12" to Time will end up in error, as the highest possible `Time` is 23:59

Comment: Works for me as I am rounding it up